# How to print an item from list

Tags: java, android

I have a list. I want print list item horizontally with delimiter.

I got output like this:

```
OderHistory: Item1-1$
OderHistory: Item2-1$
OderHistory: Item3-1$
```

But i need like this:

```
OderHistory: Item1-1$Item2-1$Item3-1
```

Code here:

```
for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
  String name = itemList.get(i).ItemName;
  String quanty = itemList.get(i).Quantity;
  Log.d("OderHistory",name+"-"+quanty+"$");
}
```

Anyone help to me!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: please mark my answer as complete if you got the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String result="";
for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
  String name = itemList.get(i).ItemName;
  String quanty = itemList.get(i).Quantity;
  result=result.concat(name+"-"+quanty+"$");
}
Log.d("OderHistory:",result);
```

Comment: If you want better performance, use a `StringBuilder` instead of `concat` and assigning the String at each iteration.

Comment: @neomega, yes using StringBuilder, we can also get same output.

Comment: @hikoo, please mark my answer as complete if you got the result.

Comment: How to do in string builder